# difference in data rendering in a facelet

Tags: facelets

The following facelet when run on a server is generating varied response on different browsers. the code when executed with IE9 as my browser renders  lines 1,2 & 14 of the code as output where as with firefox renders "Welcome" with properties of h1-tag applied to it. However when other tags such as anchor tag with href="www.google.com" is also included the execution is same in both the browsers and they display all data in specified format. What is the reason for such a difference?

```
1) <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
2) <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
3) "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
4) <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
5)    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
6)     xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
7)    >
8) <head>
9) <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
10)  <title>Insert title here</title>
11)</head>
12)<body>
13)   <ui:component>
14)     <div><h1>welcome</h1></div>     
15)   </ui:component>       
16) </body>
17) </html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to render the facelets on server side or on client side?

Comment: server side by using tomcat as the sever